# What is the correct way to handle nested Hg repositories with Mercurial/TortoiseHg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, subrepos

I'm struggling on how to correctly track nested repositories using TortoiseHg.

I have a main repository that tracks my whole project. This project contains several little plugins that are stored inside a plugins/ subdirectory.

I would love to track each plugin independently (committing and pushing to BitBucket for each one of them) while still being able to make a "whole" commit of my project, including the changes made to the plugins and pushing it to an other location (not BitBucket).

What I've done so far is creating a new repo for each of my plugins. I can commit and push them to BitBucket easily. But when I went to commit my "main" repository, TortoiseHg displays an error message saying that `abort: path 'mainrepo\\plugins\\plugin1\\plugin1.php' is inside repo 'mainrepo\\plugins\\plugin1'`.

I can see that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't tell what.

I'm using a nightly of both Mercurial and TortoiseHg (ToirtoiseHg version 0.9.3+237-ea50f793bbe4 and Mercurial-1.4.3+225-70dea42c9406) on WinXP. I read that subrepos handling was added to this TortoiseHg build, but, well, I'm not even sure subrepos is the feature I'm supposed to use here.

**Update**
I've made some progress, but still can't get it to work the way I'd like.
Here is my structure :

```
-- .hg
-- core
-- app
    -- file.php
    -- file.css
    -- plugins
        -- plugin1
            -- file1.php
        -- plugin2
            -- file2.php
```

I went to app/plugins, and cloned a plugin (named plugin3) from BitBucket here. I then created a .hgsub file at the root and added `app/plugins/plugin3 = app/plugins/plugin3` to it.
I was then able to commit my whole directory.

But then I tried to grab the latest version of plugin1 from BitBucket, so I went to app/plugins, deleted the plugin1/ folder and cloned the plugin1 from BitBucket. I then added `app/plugins/plugin1 = app/plugins/plugin1` to .hgsub but when I tried to commit it I was greeted with `abort: path 'app/plugins/plugin1/file1.php' is inside repo 'app\\plugins\\plugin1'`

The problem seems to fire when my subrepo holds the same name as a directory already tracked by Hg in the plugins/ directory.

What am I doing wrong ? Should I add/edit something special in the .hg of my plugins ?

**Update**
I've finally managed to get it to work the way I want.
I had to "manually" tell Mercurial to remove the plugins/plugin1, plugins/plugin2 directories, commit the change, then clone back the plugin1 and plugin2 from BitBucket, add `app/plugins/plugin1 = app/plugins/plugin1` to .hgsub and commit all. It worked.
The important step was committing after having deleted the plugin1/plugin2 folders.

Comment: From the doc, the line with a `.hgsub` is " The first 'nested' is the path in our working dir, and the second is a URL or path to pull from": so you shouldn't put `app/plugins/plugin3 = app/plugins/plugin3` but `app/plugins/plugin3 = bitbucket url for plugin3`. Ditto for plugin1

Comment: I've tried that, using `http://bitbucket.org/username/plugin3/`, `https://username@bitbucket.org/username/plugin3/` and even `ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/username/plugin3` as url but still have the same abort message. I've alos tried directly from the command line, and the result is the same.

Comment: sorry for not having answered your last comment, but unless your comment begins with '@VonC', I wouldn't be notified. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/ (section "Comment @username Notifications")

Comment: @VonC : Ok, new to Stack Overflow, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've finally managed to make it work the way I'd love. I'm using TortoiseHg on winXP, so I won't be able to tell you what hg calls were internally made, but I don't think anything fancy is used here.

I started with an existing repo, inside which I had a `plugins/` directory filled with `plugin1/`, `plugin/2` directories (not repositories, just simple directories).
I also had those plugins online, hosted on BitBucket.

- I first went to my `plugins/` directory, right click on `plugin1/`, `TortoiseHg => Remove Files`.
- I get back to the root of my repo, right click and `Hg Commit`
- Then I went back to my `plugins/` directory, right click, `TortoiseHg => Clone...`, I selected the http address of the plugin on bit bucket (`http://bitbucket.org/username/plugin1/` and clicked `Done`
- The back again to the root of the main repo. I created (or edited if the file already existed) a `.hgsub` file and add the `plugins/plugin1 = plugins/plugin1` line inside it.
- I was then able to either commit the main root repo, or the plugin1 repo independently

Note that the extra `remove` and `commit` steps are only required if the newly cloned repo has the same name of an already tracked directory.

Comment: Sweet. You've answered a few questions I had.

Answer (score 5):

You should try using:

- The [Forest extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ForestExtension) or
- (better choice, because officially in the Hg): the [**Subrepo feature**](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/subrepos)

> Subrepositories is a feature that allows you to treat a collection of repositories as a group.
>   This will allow you to clone, commit to, push, and pull projects and their associated libraries as a group.

Comment: Do I have to manually edit .hgsub files or does TortoiseHg handle that all by itself (through the check of some options maybe) ?

Comment: @Pixelastic: for TortoiseHg and subrepos, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083393/mercurial-subrepos-how-do-you-create-them-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: @VonC : Thanks, but I have already read that article and I don't want to have my plugins in a separate folder as my main app, I'd like them as sub-directories.  

I've updated the main question with my progress. Thanks for your time

Comment: @VonC : Ok, finally managed to get it to work. I had to tell hg to stop tracking the existing plugins, commit, the re-clone the plugins. Thanks for you help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Pixelastic: thank you for your feedback. Could you post an answer detailing the command sequence you followed to make this work (and reference your plugins as surepos)? I would vote that up ;)

Comment: @VonC : I've added a detailed answer with the all my steps.