# How to maintain a small repository of bash/python scripts

Tags: version-control

For the past several years, I've been making small (single file, 1-500 line) scripts (mostly bash & python) to automate random tasks (usually scientific data analysis). Most of these end up being one-offs, but sometimes I want to go back and revisit/change something, or end up with a rather unwieldy script that could benefit from some sort of version control. I should note that all of these scripts are done solely on my own, and don't necessarily need to be share-able.

Which type of versioning (SVN,CVS,git,Mercurial..) Has the **simplest** command structure/syntax for my use case? More importantly, the machines I connect to are behind rather finicky kerberos walls, so I'm not looking for any sophisticated server-based implementation.

I found [this thread from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512683/how-many-repositories-should-i-use-to-maintain-my-scripts-under-version-control) asking a similar question, though it didn't really talk about specific options, just whether or not I should be using a single repository.

In short, which versioning system allows for simple same-directory approach with minimal bells & whistles (only checkouts and commits needed)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I set up some sort of subversion/CVS/git repository and just throw everything in?

Yes.

For your use-case, I suppose, SVN can be best choice (with URL-based access to every object in repo you can *easy and fast* get access to any single file any revision of file and for your linear history "not the best" merge in SVN isn't problem). Local file:///-based repository will require minimum of maintenance. You can use single-repository, flat tree (all files in /trunk)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into SVN.