# Using git branches for variations of a project

Tags: git, deployment, workflow

I'm using git's branching feature to manage 5 variations of a small website.  There are 5 versions that will all be live in different subdirectories on production.  My approach to checking out the various branches to their respective folders was to:

```
mkdir foo && cd foo
git init
git remote add origin git@...:project.git
git fetch origin foo:foo
```

Where "foo" is a given branch name.  This was fine, except for that it pulled my entire repo (designs, as3 source, etc...) into those branch folders instead of just the public www folder, which is the only thing I really want on production.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this?  Git can't clone subdirectories right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way a DVCS functions (pushing/pulling a *all* repo) forces you to reason in term of **[component (coherent set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769786/vendor-branches-in-git/769941#769941)**, with their own commit lifecycle)

Your `www` folder should be in your case a [submodule (Git) or subRepo (Mercurial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392404/dvcs-how-structure-with-large-integrated-code-base-with-multiple-projects-sharin/2392900#2392900).
That way, you would be able to pull everything.

---

The other solution (if you want to keep your repo the way is is), is to define a special "release" branch (`release_foo` for `foo`) in which you remove everything but `www`.
When the development on `foo` is ready to be release, you merge on `release_foo` and remove on *that* branch what you don't need.
Not an *ideal* solution, but workable.

---

The last solution I forgot initially to mention is available since Git1.7:

**[sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336580/sparse-checkout-in-git-1-7-0)**

> Once the repository is cloned, the read-tree trick limits your "view" of the repository to **only those files or directories that are in the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file**.

In your case, you could just create one  `.git/info/sparse-checkout` with the relevant directory, and when you update your working tree, only that directory (like `foo`) would appear.
That is another solution which would:

- allows you to keep your repository unmodified
- avoid any "maintenance" work prior a delivery.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of maintenance to push release files to a separate branch.  I'm not even sure how I'd do that: after I make a change in the master branch, how would I push release files to the release branch?

Comment: I think I'll try to setup submodules if I have time.  Currently I have symlinks on the server pointing into my source/www dir :/

Comment: @Trevor: I would consider the "maintenance" work to be very small, since the merge should be trivial (you duplicate `foo` on `foo_release`), and the only modification you do on `foo_release` is to remove a bunch of directories.

Comment: @Trevor: just added one more solution I forgot initially: **sparse checkout**. See my updated answer.

Comment: @VonC sparse checkout sounds perfect. Going to look into that - thanks!

Comment: @VonC regarding maintenance: having to manually delete files on every push to prod - especially when making minor tweaks and pushing more than once per hour during dev - is too much work. Writing a script to do it is fine too, but it's borderline overkill for the size of this quickturn project. Plus, I'm lazy.

Comment: @Trevor: "Plus, I'm lazy": Best. Justification. Evaaar. You must be smart, then ;) http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/711177/are_smart_people_lazy.html?cat=7 (I totally agree with you, btw, about the cost of the "maintenance" approach)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix stuff that you want to keep private into your releasable product.

I'd suggest that you keep your products (html, php, js, img, etc) separate from the sources. Keep the sources in a project or projects, and keep the products separately in another project. Or even just build the products dynamically on demand with a build script that copies/generates/etc the output from the sources. That way it is easy to point to which sources generated what output.

Comment: I like this approach, but this a small/fast project and don't have time to generate a decent build process. Pushing release files to a separate repo also seems like a lot of work to do manually.  Because of this, I might take the submodule approach mentioned in VonC's answer. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (AFAIK) a git will only clone the whole repository. Using a separate repository for deployment could be an option. Given git's flexibility, I wouldn't be surprised if you could push/pull from a master development repository, and just push a single branch to a second deployment repository, all from the same local. But I've never tried that out.