# Two close repos in Mercurial

Tags: linux, mercurial, repository, shared

I have a project I'm currently working on, which I am contemplating making open source, but I definitely want to keep it closed-source for the time being. Inside this project, I have a sort of subproject that I want to make public, so anyone can access/fork it.

So here's what I want:

A mercurial SCC with:

- `Repo 1`: All files from `/dir/project/` - Private repo, requires username/password to pull/push/fork/browse etc.
- `Repo 2`: Some files from `/dir/project/stuff` - Public repo, but requires username/password to modify.

How can I do this? Is there a better way I can do this? I'm using my shared hosting Linux environment to do this, so is symbolic linking a better idea?

I'm open to all suggestions thanks, still a bit of a HG newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "**[subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository?action=show&redirect=subrepos)**" to define the two parts of your project:

- your parent repo would be the private one, with a reference (in a .hgsub file) to your public repo ()
- your public repo woud be stored in a public referential, with no knowledge of the private part.

(No symlink necessary here)
See also in the same kind of problem the SO question "[Mercurial Subrepos - How do you create them and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083393/mercurial-subrepos-how-do-you-create-them-and-how-do-they-work)".

> Subrepositories is a feature that allows you to treat a collection of repositories as a group. This will allow you to clone, commit to, push, and pull projects and their associated libraries as a group.

Comment: Sounds like what I'm after. Thanks, will try it.

Comment: @VonC Not quite following, sorry. Where would I make each repository?
Keep in mind, I could very easily want to share 2 repos from /dir/project/stuff, because I'd have two different 'plugins' in there.
Would I be better off creating a /dir/plugins/plugin1 repo with the files there, and have it update in the main repo when I commit there? Is that what you are saying?
The documentation on subrepos is a bit confuzzling...

Comment: @dawmail333: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083393/mercurial-subrepos-how-do-you-create-them-and-how-do-they-work is more detailed, but the idea remains to create as many subrepo you need within a parent repository (like `/dir/project` in your case)

Comment: Herp a derp, I just realised that I don't have to make a repo directly in the referenced directory... I can easily make a repo off in /dir2/stuff that claims the files in /dir/project/stuff, right?

Comment: @dawmail333: yes, a subrepo is a reference from any other remote repo, that you will checkout within a parent repo (hence the notion of nested repos)

Comment: @VonC I think I need to go back over hg, must have missed some of the basics.

Comment: Perhaps making a repo with multiple branches would be a smarter idea.

Comment: @VonC, I changed my system, so I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539449/importing-a-mercurial-repository-automatically-e-g-svn-externals

Comment: I still marked your answer though, because if that were exactly what I were after, it would work. My fundamental misunderstandings of HG caused me to ask the wrong question.